# Can't connect to MongoDB on VPS

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to connect from MongoDB compass to my database which is on VPS. MongoDB itself is working on the VPS. As well I allow firewall to connect from my IP. But it's still doesn't allow me to go. Error - `connect ECONNREFUSED "ipaddress:port"`
I also tried to use SSH tunnel with the same IP and port and I'm getting confused which SSH username and SSH password I need to use?

**I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on my VPS.**

I checked so many resources on how to connect but doesn't find any helpful. First the problem was with Firewall and allowance of ports and IP. But now i'm 100% sure that I allow it in firewall.

For SSH Hostname - I use my IP

SSH Tunnel port - I use port which I allow

[image]

GOAL: Any solution how I can connect my MongoDB which is on VPS to MongoDB Compass? I'm really clueless on how to get it.

**EDIT1**

This error I receive after I'm trying to connect with MongoDB Compass -

```
Error creating SSH Tunnel: (SSH) Channel open failure: Connection refused
```

When I change the port I receive this error - `Error creating SSH Tunnel: connect EADDRINUSE`

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? But srsly you are not even telling what os your vps runs - but still its little code but configuration my guess is here

Comment: @Estradiaz My bad. I'll edit main question. Ubuntu 18.04 I'm using.

Comment: `which SSH username and SSH password I need to use?` lets me ask - ssh is working? when you `ssh username@host` you get a valid connection? so did you setup ssh? most likly because it is remote to begin with ^^

Comment: Yes, I connect with ssh root@my.ip.adress. I'm sorry if my questions a little bit not correct, it's my first time working with VPS.

Comment: and you use those also for ssh tunneling? then its not a ssh error but some mongodb error, ... when you are sshed your mongo host is localhost:defaultport? - i am guessing right now

Comment: Im getting super confused is it possible to open a chat with you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217139/discussion-between-hexycode-and-estradiaz).